# Facebook share button updated with ajax does not display correct link

Tags: jquery, ajax, facebook, facebook-like

I am working on an image-viewing site.
I am trying to update a Facebook share button whenever content on the page is changed with ajax. Each image has a permalink, which I would like the facebook share button to direct to.  However, the share button just directs to the root url of my page.
this is my code:

```
$.ajax({
....
    permalink = response["permalink"];
    $("#fbposition").html("<div class='fb-share-button' data-href='" + permalink + "' data-type='box_count'></div>");
....
});

$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).ajaxComplete(function(){
        try{
            FB.XFBML.parse(); 
        }catch(ex){}
    });
....
```

Comment: Are you sure `permalink` is the value you're expecting? Does the facebook share button get re-rendered properly by `FB.XFBML.parse()` ?

Comment: i checked the permalink, and it is correct. the facebook share button gets re-rendered but links to the root_url :((